# Uploading a file via test cafe causes an error with Fine Uploader library

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, fine-uploader, testcafe

When uploading a file when running the app within test cafe I get the following issue and stack trace:

```
hammerhead.js:2 [Fine Uploader 5.15.6] Failed to retrieve key name for 0.  Reason: null
window.console.(anonymous function) @ hammerhead.js:2
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ bundle.js:80994
r @ hammerhead.js:9
value @ hammerhead.js:2
./node_modules/fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader.core.js.qq.log @ bundle.js:26539
log @ bundle.js:27561
onFailure @ bundle.js:32615
_handleKeynameFunction @ bundle.js:32621
_determineKeyName @ bundle.js:32603
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:26829
promise @ bundle.js:33630
start @ bundle.js:33688
sendNext @ bundle.js:29341
sendNext @ bundle.js:29335
sendNext @ bundle.js:29335
now @ bundle.js:29557
maybeSendDeferredFiles @ bundle.js:29530
maybeDefer @ bundle.js:29512
start @ bundle.js:29565
upload @ bundle.js:29578
_uploadFile @ bundle.js:28602
_onSubmitCallbackSuccess @ bundle.js:28412
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:26829
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:28082
Promise.then (async)
_handleCheckedCallback @ bundle.js:28080
_upload @ bundle.js:28593
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:28489
then @ bundle.js:27079
_onValidateCallbackSuccess @ bundle.js:28488
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:26829
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:28082
Promise.then (async)
_handleCheckedCallback @ bundle.js:28080
_onValidateBatchCallbackSuccess @ bundle.js:28465
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:26829
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:28082
Promise.then (async)
_handleCheckedCallback @ bundle.js:28080
_prepareItemsForUpload @ bundle.js:28501
addFiles @ bundle.js:27429
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:141335
eventChannel @ bundle.js:98272
_callee$ @ bundle.js:141334
tryCatch @ bundle.js:3376
invoke @ bundle.js:3603
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:3424
r @ hammerhead.js:9
value @ hammerhead.js:2
step @ bundle.js:141141
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:141141
Promise.then (async)
step @ bundle.js:141141
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:141141
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:141141
uploadFile @ bundle.js:141362
runCallEffect @ bundle.js:99260
runEffect @ bundle.js:99182
next @ bundle.js:99062
currCb @ bundle.js:99135
takeCb @ bundle.js:99213
put @ bundle.js:98192
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:98280
r @ hammerhead.js:9
value @ hammerhead.js:2
emit @ bundle.js:98145
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:98710
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:140132
continueAllFiles @ bundle.js:140131
onClick @ bundle.js:139876
apply @ bundle.js:44333
baseInvoke @ bundle.js:45997
apply @ bundle.js:44334
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:52088
Button._this.handleClick @ bundle.js:108472
callCallback @ bundle.js:63947
dispatchEvent @ hammerhead.js:3
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:63986
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:63843
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ bundle.js:63857
executeDispatch @ bundle.js:64241
executeDispatchesInOrder @ bundle.js:64263
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ bundle.js:64361
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ bundle.js:64372
forEachAccumulated @ bundle.js:64340
processEventQueue @ bundle.js:64517
runEventQueueInBatch @ bundle.js:66996
handleTopLevel @ bundle.js:67005
handleTopLevelImpl @ bundle.js:66736
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:74471
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:65719
dispatchEvent @ bundle.js:66810
(anonymous) @ hammerhead.js:4
```

Debugging the stack trace when running "determineKeyName" the keyNameLogic is a function. This function is then run and returns undefined.

I believe the function being run is this one:

```
objectProperties: {
      key(id) {
        return get(awsKeys, id);
      },
    },
```

Which suggests perhaps "awsKeys" is undefined.

Has anyone got any idea what could cause this? performing the same steps outside of testCafe testing env works fine (clicking upload and selecting a file from the directory)

One difference I can see if uploading outside of test Cafe creates a File Object, where as uploading via test Cafe creates a "Blob" object.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: What version of testcafe do you use? You can show version if run `testcafe -v` in your terminal

Comment: Hi I'm using version 0.18.6 of testcafe

Comment: code to upload I'm using is: `.setFilesToUpload(Selector('#upload'), './video.mov')`.

However if i pause the test and manually click the upload button and select a file I still get the above error.

perhaps hamerhead is affecting one of the requests/responses?

Comment: updated to version 0.19.0 of testcafe but same issue exists

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue on the latest FileUploader (5.16.0) and all works good. It is a difficult to understand a reason of the issue. So, I need a code example for further research

Answer (score 2):

Currently unaware of a fix for this from the integration test side. I'm thinking a bug report or feature request needs to be made to testcafe or hammerhead for modifying the file(s) before upload.

If you're able to fix the client side code, you can add something like this to check if the file is a Blob at runtime and if so convert it to a file.

```
// if no lastModified set then image was uploaded as a Blob instead of a File
if (!image.lastModified) {
  image = new File([image], image.name);
}
```

I'm not very familiar with the Fine Uploader library, but another possible solution (also client-side) might be to use the [`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) api, however you want to make sure you call the [`URL.revokeObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) method on cleanup.  I was testing with [react-avatar-editor](https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor#props) which allows the image to be passed either as a URL or a file.